# PHP MySQL to SQLite 3, do equivalent functions exist?

Tags: php, sqlite

A developer I hired decided to use MySQL for a small project. Now he won't respond to me when I tell him I want to switch to SQLite 3.

I was just wondering if there are alternatives for these functions in PHP:

- mysqli_set_charset
- mysqli_connect
- mysqli_select_db
- mysqli_query
- mysqli_fetch_array
- mysqli_fetch_object
- mysqli_free_result
- mysqli_insert_id
- mysqli_affected_rows
- mysqli_num_rows
- mysqli_fetch_row
- mysqli_num_fields
- mysqli_field_count
- mysqli_fetch_fields
- mysqli_real_escape_string
- mysqli_error
- mysqli_errno
- mysqli_get_server_info
- mysqli_get_client_info

I scoured the PHP manual.

Comment: I strongly recommend PDO. I'm using it to copy rows between mysql and sqlite3 databases just fine.

Comment: honestly I have to question why you would need some of these... Are you just trying to verify that when you start changing code you will be safe!? Or did your programmer actually use these?

Comment: As an aside, a developer should always respond to you. However, bear in mind if he has already committed work on MySQLi, he may be right to charge a separate fee to redo the work he has already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite3](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3.php) has it's own API separate from `mysql`/`mysqli`.

You can't use `mysqli_*` functions on an `SQLite` database.

---

MySQL and SQLite share the SQL-language so queries written for one will likely work in the other. There are some caveats though.

It's relatively easy to write a database layer that can work with both MySQL and SQLite.

Comment: I have to find a library then.

Comment: @Xees: I would just use PDO for both - there are MySQL and SQLite adapters available.